# Can I change proxy settings on my stock Android browser?

Tags: proxy

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3, and I'm not experienced enough in Android to want to root it yet.

However, I need a proxy server. Is there any way to change the proxy settings (for both WiFi and network, either through the phone or over adb)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to have a proxy server on your phone? Or do you just need to change the proxy settings of your phone, so your data goes through that proxy?

Comment: @geffchang Just need to change proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

With terminal on your droid or via adb

The android web browser will read the proxy settings in its settings database.

Spawn a shell:

```
> adb shell
```

Init sqlite3 database manager to edit the settings database.

```
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
```

Run the query bruh.

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO system VALUES(99,’http_proxy', 'proxy:port');
```

Close the session.

```
sqlite>.exit
```

Profit.

Comment: Upvoting due to the sass

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[Orbot - Proxy With Tor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.android)** for proxies through supported browser called **[Orweb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.browser)**.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 5 and newer, you can enable proxy servers globally on a per-WiFi-network basis.

1. Go to Settings: WiFi
2. Long-press on the network you want to use a proxy for
3. Select Modify network
4. Click Advanced
5. Fill in your proxy details and save
6. You can then use the [Proxy Troubleshooter app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=software.geeky.proxytroubleshooter) to verify that you’re using the proxy you configured.

Some vendors made this setting available in Android 4.4.4, but not all. It’s available in stock Android starting with version 5.

Answer (score -1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4, but there should be something similar to `Settings > More Networks > Mobile Networks > Access Point Names > [APN]` in the S3. You can change the proxy and port from there.